# MySQL Using merging two identical tables and use GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, database, group-by, union-all

I want to select from two identical tables using UNION ALL and GROUP BY. However, the Group BY doesn't work. Here is my query:

```
SELECT type , COUNT(subscription.id) as number ,SUM(subscription.amount) as total 
FROM subscription 
WHERE DATE(subscription.timestamp) BETWEEN '2022-10-18' AND '2022-10-18'
UNION ALL
SELECT type , COUNT(archive_subscription.id) as number ,SUM(archive_subscription.amount) as total 
FROM archive_subscription   
WHERE DATE(archive_subscription.timestamp) BETWEEN '2022-10-18' AND '2022-10-18'
GROUP BY type
```

The result is like the following:

| type | number | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 180000 |
| 1 | 1 | 80000 |

What I want to do is two merge both table using GROUP BY but it won't work:

| type | number | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 260000 |

Please, any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using UNION, COUNT and GROUP BY in a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222603/using-union-count-and-group-by-in-a-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first subquery in your union is missing its `GROUP BY` clause.  Instead, try taking a union first and then aggregate:

```sql
SELECT type, COUNT(*) AS number, SUM(amount) AS total
FROM
(
    SELECT type, amount
    FROM subscription
    WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2022-10-18' AND '2022-10-18'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT type, amount
    FROM archive_subscription
    WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2022-10-18' AND '2022-10-18'
) t
GROUP BY type;
```

Note that the ranges in your `WHERE` clauses are trivial.  If you really want to restrict to a single date, just use `WHERE timestamp = '2022-10-18'` instead.

Comment: It returns nothing. However, when I remove the where clause of the dates in both select statements ,it will return result. I tried to put the where clause after the alias "t" but it says "Unknown column 'subscription.timestamp' in 'where clause'"

Comment: I flagged the `WHERE` clause already and I also can't see your data.  My query is semantically correct.

Comment: the time will be a range between two dates. I wrote the same date from simplicity. you query is correct. The only thing I need to add is the where clause correctly.

Comment: Just use the actual dates on which you want to filter.  Note that if no data from either table matches the timestamp range, you won't get any results.